# Using Esri ASCII Grid as DEM + Reprojecting

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcgis-pro, dem

I've downloaded *.txt files from this site: https://ide.cat/geonetwork/srv/eng/catalog.search#/metadata/model-digital-terreny-5x5-v1r0

I used `Copy Raster` tool to import one of the files with `Esri Grid Format` option. The DEM seems to be created fine but I can't seem to reproject it properly.

On the Catalan version of the metadata page: https://ide.cat/geonetwork/srv/cat/catalog.search#/metadata/model-digital-terreny-5x5-v1r0

I noticed they specify the coordinate system:
[image]

So I selected `ETRS89` from Geographic Coordinate System.

[image]
[image]

But the projection placed the raster in the same place as before (middle of the sea):

[image]
[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The first entry in the list in your screenshot tells you the CRS is 25831 i.e [ETRS89 / UTM zone 31N](https://epsg.io/25831).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the links you provided I downloaded the data. Opening the text file its clear that even though it ends with a txt file name extension the contents conforms to an ASCII grid interchange file with float 32 values.

[image: ASCII File]

If you open the xml (metadata file) that accompanies it you will discover the coordinate system is UTM 31N

[image: Metadata]

Knowing these two pieces of information you simply use the Copy raster and at the same time set the environment setting.

[image: Tool]

[image: Tool environment settings]

The result is the correctly located raster in ESRI grid format.

[image: Results]

Comment: Thank you so much for this. May I ask you few more questions? How did you get the XML file? (couldn't find it) And second - can I use the same process for a folder of files?

Comment: The xml was in one of the zip files I accessed, you will need to view it from file explorer. Yes a very simple model with an iterator could automate all this.